# I don't want to check out a specific branch even by accident

Tags: git

I have a repository which has two root commits, the old branch is barely used but if I accidentally check it out out of habit then it'd either run forever to checkout if I break it then it leaves a state which needs to be reset before it's usable.

How can I tell git to not check out branch A? It doesn't exist locally, it gets autocreated from origin/A. So, how do I stop autocreation on checkout -b? Setting up

```
[branch "A"]
  remote = fubar
```

doesn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run:

```
git checkout foo
```

and branch `foo` does not exist but branch `origin/foo` *does* exist, Git checks out the commit to which `origin/foo` points, then creates `foo` with `origin/foo` set as the upstream of `foo`, pointing to the same commit.  This is called *DWIM mode*, for *Do What I Mean:* Git assumes that you *meant* to type:

```
git checkout --track origin/foo
```

and somehow accidentally left out the `--track origin/` part.

Git has no way to completely disable this DWIM mode.  But there are three total cases where DWIM either *doesn't* fire, or *cannot* fire.  These are:

- Branch `foo` already exists, pointing to some commit.  Since your branch names are *yours*, you can just create a branch named `foo`, so that `foo` exists.  Pick some commit that it should point to, and create it:

  ```
  branch foo a123456
  ```

  (assuming, of course, that `a123456` is a valid commit).  Now `git checkout foo` will switch you to commit `a123456` and branch `foo`.
- Branch `foo` does not exist, but neither does `origin/foo`.  There's no `origin/foo` remote-tracking name to supply as the argument to `git checkout --track origin/foo`.  Now `git checkout foo` will simply fail.

  Your remote-tracking names are *yours*, so you can simply delete `origin/foo`, but there's a hitch.  The deletion is easy:

  ```
  git branch -r -d origin/foo
  ```

  Now it's gone!  Unfortunately, running `git fetch` will bring it back, as long as the Git at `origin` has a branch named `foo`, because you've told your Git—probably unintentionally; this is the default—that your Git should slavishly update or re-create all your `origin/*` names to match `origin`'s branch names every time you run `git fetch` to remote `origin`.  This means that to make the deletion stick, you would have to convince the Git at `origin` to remove branch `foo`.

  That may be possible, and may even be easy.  It might be what you should do here.  But origin's Git is not your Git, and I can't tell you whether this is appropriate to do to someone else's Git.  You'll have to find or figure that out for yourself.
- Last, the DWIM mode *fails* if there exist two or more possible `foo`s.  That is, `git checkout foo` became `git checkout --track origin/foo`, but it did so only *because*, having listed *all* of your remote-tracking names, the only one that resembled `foo` was `origin/foo`.

  You can have more than one remote.  In fact, you can have more than one remote even for a single Git repository.  So you can just add a second remote:

  ```
  git remote add origin2 <url>
  ```

  where `<url>` is the same URL you use for your `origin`, then run `git fetch`.  Now you will have not only `origin/foo` but also `origin2/foo`, and `git checkout foo` won't know *which one* to DWIM, so it won't.

  The drawback here is that this will also cause all *other* DWIM `git checkout` operations to fail.  If that doesn't bother you, you can stop here.  If it does, you can fix it: you can set up `origin2` as a *single-branch tracker*, by altering the setting for `origin2`.  You can do this after creating the extra remote by editing `.git/config`, or you can do it *while* creating `origin2` by using:

  ```
  git remote add origin2 <url> -t foo
  ```

  so that `origin2` is a single-branch tracker.  Now you'll only have `origin2/foo`, not `origin2/master`, not `origin2/develop`, and not any other such name.

Comment: `git remote add origin2 $(git remote get-url origin) -t foo; git fetch --all` indeed makes `git checkout foo` fail, this is a wonderful trick. And I never heard of a single branch remote before, this is extremely useful.

Comment: "you would have to convince the Git at origin to remove branch foo" - you just have to tell git not to fetch it. config `remote.<branchname>.fetch`

Comment: @RaymondChen: yes, I mentioned this in the last alternative. The problem with doing it for `origin` is that you must list *every* branch you *do* want from `origin`, which isn't really workable in the general case. It would be helpful if the fetch refspec list allowed specific blacklists.

Answer (score 0):

You can create alias of your branch.You can use below mentioned command for it:

```
git symbolic-ref refs/heads/branch1 refs/heads/branch2
```

So here whenever you will try to checkout into **branch1** you will reach into **branch2**.

Comment: This should in fact work, but I'd avoid it as it has some weird behaviors. In particular if you ask Git to delete the symbolic branch, it deletes the non-symbolic branch instead. (This is perhaps a bug.  I last tested it quite some time ago, but I doubt it's been fixed.)